# How to change/delete between blocks and braces using VSVIM

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vi, visual-studio-addins, vsvim

I am using **vsvim** and I think that it is a great tool.

The only issue I have is regarding changing/deleting text between braces and parentheses doesn't seem to work.

Here some examples I have verified in **gvim**, but do not seem to work in **vsvim**:

- `di(` *deletes the inner (...) block where the cursor*
- `da(` *deletes the inner (...) block where the cursor and removes the () characters too*
- `ci(` *changes the inner (...) block where the cursor is.*
- `ci{` *changes inside a {}*
- `ca{` *changes inside a {} and removes the {} characters too*

I assume these are just features that have not been added.

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These issues are now fixed in VsVim 1.2. I tried all of your commands locally and they worked for me.

[VsVim 1.2 Release Notes](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Release-Notes)

Comment: +1, They are currently scheduled to be fixed in the 1.3 release or possibly as a bug fix on 1.2 which will be released in about 1 week.

Comment: These ended up fixed in 1.2. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The developer has commented  below that these features are now available as of version 1.2.

The `i(`/`a(` and `i{`/`a{` text objects are not listed in the [supported features](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Supported-Features).

Also, for the text objects that are supported there is a note at the bottom stating that there are quirks with the current implementation.

Note that the page above has not been updated since April of 2011.  You may want to poke the developer and see if any of this info has changed since he is now past a 1.0 release.

Comment: Just released a new version (1.2) which has these features.

Comment: Excellent news.  Updated the answer to make a note of this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have vsvim but I would assume there are many alternatives should do the same thing and I noticed that you don't use the '%' key in any of your example, so, here's one you can try:

- ? { ENTER c % *changes inside a {} and removes the {} characters too*

i.e. use ? or / to position the cursor on { } or ( ) blocks and use % to do operations on that block.